# PID's mapping in global and namespace

Tags: namespaces, kernel, pid

Linux kernel source code http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/pid_namespace.c which gives the idea about how PID namespace is created.

Can any one please give me an idea where exactly PID's in the Namespace related are maintained apart from the global one, and how do I map those PID's?